# How to distinguish two MKPolyline's in viewForOverlay:

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, polyline, mkoverlay

I am loading multiple `MKPolylines` as `overlays` onto an `MKMapView`.  I would like to be able to distinguish these some how so change things like color, line width, etc.

But, when `viewForOverlay:` gets called, it sees all my `MKPolylines` the same, which doesn't allow me to change any of them.

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolyline class]]) {
        MKPolylineView *aView = [[[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:(MKPolyline*)overlay] autorelease];
        aView.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
        MKZoomScale currentZoomScale = (CGFloat)(mapView.bounds.size.width / mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width);
        aView.lineWidth = MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(currentZoomScale);

        return aView;
    }

    // Want to color my next overlay red

    return  nil;
}
```

How can I do this?  Could I somehow attach tag to each `MKPolyline`?  Or, another, better way to do this?

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464098/different-coloured-polygon-overlays).  It's about polygons but it should work with polylines.

Comment: Anna, this is exactly what I wanted.  Didn't realize it had a title property.  Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MKPolyline` inherits from `MKShape` which has a settable `title` (and `subtitle`) property which you can use to tell them apart.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464098/different-coloured-polygon-overlays) has an example of how to use it with `MKPolygon` objects.

If `title` and `subtitle` are not sufficient for your requirements, then you can subclass as Mundi commented.

Answer (score 0):

`MKPolyLine` <strike>is a subclass of `UIView`. Thus I would go with tags. This also makes it quite easy to refer to the lines when you need them (with `viewWithTag`)</strike> could be subclassed to add a tag-like identifier.

Comment: You're thinking of `MKPolyLineView`.

Comment: You're right. My mistake. In this case - why not subclass MKPolyLine and add your own identifier?

Answer (score 0):

i'm using mkcircle as an example

```
  MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:currentPoint radius:radius];
    [circle setTitle:@"circle1"];
    [map addOverlay:circle];


- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    NSLog(@"overlay %@",overlay);

    if ([[overlay title] isEqualToString:@"circle1"]){

    circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    //circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];

    return circleView;
    }

}
```