# How to Remove Bad GPS Coordinate

Tags: ios, mapkit

As shown in the image below, there is a sudden jump in GPS coordinate while I keep track of user activity (walking, biking or driving).

I do not know how to fix this problem even though I have already attempted multiple ways to solve, but as a reference I also posted my code below.

In this image screenshot, I parked my car and walked to campus and came to my office, but it shows me that I went to Harvest Ln which is not right.
[image]

```
   -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{



    iNEAT_o_GamesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iNEAT_o_GamesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    CoordinateModel *coord = [[CoordinateModel alloc] init];

    ActivityType currentActivityType = [DataManager sharedInstance].activityType;

    for(int i=0;i<locations.count;i++){
        CLLocation * newLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:i];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theLocation = newLocation.coordinate;
        CLLocationAccuracy theAccuracy = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;
        NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

        if (locationAge > 30.0)
            continue;

        //Select only valid location and also location with good accuracy
        if(newLocation!=nil&&theAccuracy>0
           &&theAccuracy<2000
           &&(!(theLocation.latitude==0.0&&theLocation.longitude==0.0))){
            coord.latitude = theLocation.latitude;
            coord.longitude = theLocation.longitude;

                   if (currentActivityType == 0) {
                        // walking
                        [appDelegate.walkingCoordinates addObject:coord];
                    }
                    else if(currentActivityType == 1) {
                        [appDelegate.bikingCoordinates addObject:coord];
                    }
                    else if(currentActivityType == 2) {
                        // driving
                        [appDelegate.drivingCoordinates addObject:coord];
                    }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you walk inside a building? Were you walking near tall buildings? GPS is most accurate when you have a line of sight to the satellites. This will be disrupted when you're indoors or otherwise out of sight. That graph looks like the results of loosing accuracy and the device trying to guess where you're at. Start logging the reported accuracy when you test and I'm sure you'll find that it's just losing its lock when it makes large jumps like that.

Comment: Skladek,Yes, that is known fact obviously, I am in the building now. But my question is how to fix that problem.

Comment: Turn on wifi, that can help some if a wifi connection is available, but there isn't a good solution to get a lock indoors. Something like iBeacons placed around the building would be able to pinpoint your location indoors, but this requires the devices to be placed in any building you want to track within. Using GPS alone, there isn't anything you can do. It's a limitation of the technology.

Comment: How to remove this bad signal?

Comment: CW0007007,Please respect.

Comment: You're checking that the accuracy is within 0 and 2000. That's measured in meters. Your upper limit is approx 1.25 miles. Set the upper limit lower and only map the coordinates if they're within the acceptable range.

Comment: You mean instead of 0 to 2000 , make it 0 to 1.25 for walking. Am I right ?

Comment: He means that 2000 is equal to 1.25 miles. So you are accepting any GPS coordinate that has a circle of imprecision with a radius of 1.25 miles. This means that your real position could be anywhere inside that circle. You should lower that radius to a more reliable value, i.e. 50 for 50 meters, depending on the precision you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added another condition for walking activity and limited only accuracy between 0-60 meters. and work perfectly fine. Thanks Allessandro and Skladek feedback above.

```
 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{




    iNEAT_o_GamesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iNEAT_o_GamesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    CoordinateModel *coord = [[CoordinateModel alloc] init];

    ActivityType currentActivityType = [DataManager sharedInstance].activityType;

    for(int i=0;i<locations.count;i++){
        CLLocation * newLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:i];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theLocation = newLocation.coordinate;
        CLLocationAccuracy theAccuracy = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;
        NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];

        if (locationAge > 30.0)
            continue;

        //Select only valid location and also location with good accuracy
        if(newLocation!=nil&&theAccuracy>0
           &&theAccuracy<2000
           &&(!(theLocation.latitude==0.0&&theLocation.longitude==0.0))){
            coord.latitude = theLocation.latitude;
            coord.longitude = theLocation.longitude;

                   if (currentActivityType == 0 && theAccuracy<60) {
                        // walking
                        [appDelegate.walkingCoordinates addObject:coord];
                    }
                    else if(currentActivityType == 1) {
                        [appDelegate.bikingCoordinates addObject:coord];
                    }
                    else if(currentActivityType == 2) {
                        // driving
                        [appDelegate.drivingCoordinates addObject:coord];
                    }
        }
    }
}
```